# Is there a way or formula to transilerate to know the pronunciation in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am aware of the formula to translate from one language to other through google Sheets. But I would like to know how to covert/transilerate the destination word to english to understand how to pronounce the word. Is there an approach that I can use?

For example A2, has the english word "Hello" - through translation using the formula =GOOGLETRANSLATE($A2,"en","ml") . Now since I do not how to read the target language "ml" I would like to know if google sheets can show the transilerated version of "ml" word.

En is "Hello" is translated to ml as "ഹലോ"

Thanks

Comment: I reviewed all the documentation for the [GOOGLETRANSLATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093331), and it has a very straight forward process. It will only translate the information in the written language, but not the pronunciation.  Maybe you can do a feature request for this option by following the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/support#developer_product_feedback)